# Converting retrained_graph.pb to the tflite model

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am unable to convert retrained_graph.pb file (inception-V3) model obtained from retrain to .tflite model for android app.

Code to write retrained_graph.pb file is:

```py
    output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph.as_graph_def(), [FINAL_TENSOR_NAME])
    with gfile.FastGFile(graph_file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

I get a error while converting to tflite as:
RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags {'serve'} could not be found in SavedModel.

Code is:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

So someone please help me with this issue So that I can easily convert .pb file to .tflite file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to convert to retrained_graph.pb model file obtained from transfer learning approach to tflite file using following command:

> toco  --graph_def_file=/saved_model.pb
>   --output_file=C:/Users/sunil.gc/tf-python/src/saved_model.tflite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --input_shape=1,299,299,3 --input_array=Mul --output_array=final_result --inference_type=FLOAT --input_type=FLOAT

Detail tutorial is in given [link](https://kharbari.com/how-to-convert-pb-to-tflite-format/)